# Value of type 'UIView' has no member 'image'

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to get a particular UIImage in one of my subviews, but am getting the following error `Value of type 'UIView' has no member 'image'` with

```
for subview in self.view.subviews.filter{$0 is UIImageView} {
    print(subview.image)
}
```

I understand how `self.view.subviews` are of the type `UIView`

But what am I supposed to do?

Comment: It's not because you filter that you "trasnform"... `self.view.subviews.filter` is still an array of `UIView`, which is the initial type of `subviews`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `case` pattern (like in `switch` statements) in a `for` loop. This has the slight advantage of not creating an intermediate array.

See also: https://alisoftware.github.io/swift/pattern-matching/2016/05/16/pattern-matching-4/

```swift
for case let subview as UIImageView in self.view.subviews {
    print(subview.image)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're filtering the `subviews` array, but you still need to [*cast*](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TypeCasting.html) them to a `UIImageView` — for example:

```
for subview in self.view.subviews.filter{ $0 is UIImageView } {
    if let imageView = subview as? UIImageView {
        print(imageView.image)
    }
}
```

However, this is a bit repetitive. You probably want [`compactMap(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2950916-compactmap) instead.

```
for imageView in self.view.subviews.compactMap { $0 as? UIImageView } {
    print(imageView.image)
}
```